# gwt response at run as web application

Tags: gwt

In my gwt application,i am using php code for back end process...i can get response from that php file when i deploy on iis server...
but i can't get response from that php file when i running from the eclipse...

(i.e)
can get response from this url "http://localhost/sample/index.php"

can't get response from this url "http://localhost:8888/sample/index.php" it returns my php code...

Comment: I think php runs only on HTTP server like apache (May be wrong). But from eclipse you are starting jetty server which is an application server. That may be the reason you are not getting expected output

Answer (score 1):

It's probably possible to run PHP on Jetty, too: See these [instructions](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Jetty+and+PHP) - not sure, if they still work with Jetty 6, and I really haven't tried it.

But I would recommend to simply run a separate PHP server (maybe deployed from a separate Eclipse project). See this GWT FAQ entry: [How do I use my own server in hosted mode instead of GWT's built-in Jetty instance](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_hosted_mode_instead_of_GWT%27s)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the gwt -noserver option

"The -noserver option instructs hosted mode to not start the embedded Jetty instance. In its place, you would run the J2EE container of your choice and simply use that in place of the embedded Jetty instance."

I don't know if this would solve your problem